# Nginx and Cloudflare: err_too_many_redirects

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

The error **err_too_many_redirect**s appears in the browser [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y74vT.png) but nothing comes out in the nginx error log and I just registered the site in cloudflare. All traffic is redirected to HTTPS

Comment: Please translate your question to english. StackOverflow is english-only website.

Comment: I already translated it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error generally occurs in Wordpress Sites which is due to a re-direct header sent by PHP.

So This is due to following reason:

1. You have enabled HTTPS redirect on your website either by ngin or php.
2. Cloudflare tries to open your site http://example.com and proxy it with https
3. When Cloudflare tries to open http://example.com, your site tells it to open https://example.com and cloudflare again tries to open http://example.com
4. This forms a redirect loop and due to which site could not open.

The best way to solve this is :

1. Disable HTTPS Redirect from your server side.
2. Enable Flexible SSL from Cloudflare
3. Enter a page rule on Cloudflare with input as http://*.example.com to Always use HTTPS